# InnoDB + Windows 10 "Storage Spaces" =?

Tags: windows-8.1, mysql, storage-spaces, innodb

Ok, I think I can repeat this problem.

Win 8.1 Pro x64 . Drive S: is "Storage Spaces" mirror made of two 250 GB HD's.
Drive C: is SanDisk SSD 120 GB

WAMP/MySQL Inno DB consistently refuses to start when installed on s:\wamp64
dreaded "orange W" all the time. Sql.log reveal corrupted data file, consistently.

While if installed on C:\wamp64 there are no problems whatsoever. "big, green W" all the time.

I clearly remember there was my.ini  InnoDB variable that was a solution. But  I failed to save this info,

So. Has anybody else had the same problem? InnoDB on "Storage Spaces" refusing to start or run with the corrupted data file.

Thanks All

**UPDATE**

The plot is thickening. I have c:\wamp64, but I moved data dir to s:\mysql\data
And it works? Big green W ...

So it seems W8.1 PRO+ InnoDB has no problem with this "Storage Spaces" mirror?

I am now too tired to move everything to s: ... perhaps it might work since yesterday (13 Nov) there was yet another large w8.1 update.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

Apologies for phraseology. Explanation of "plot thickens" is [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/plot+thickens).

Thinking of the issues it seems the logical explanation is that InnoDB refuses  to create things on the first run, in the data folder which happens to be the "Storage Spaces".

To remedy the problem (aka "solve the issue"), I started it on the standard drive (SSD) and run it. Then I shut down and moved the MySQL data folder to S: drive (the "Storage Spaces" Mirror of two HD's). And all was fine.

*Important caveat*: On the two HD's making my "Storage Spaces" mirror I have switched off Write caching. As advised in the official on-line documentation.

*Moot point*: InnoDB official doc advises **not** to use NTFS. This is NTFS on  my drives. Is this critical or bad or irrelevant, I do not know.

So, if someone suspects of having the same problem. Here it is:

**The clear and actual question**:

Installing and starting mySQL+InnoDB on Windows 10 "Storage Spaces". Is this possible, problem-ridden, not an issue ?

Thank you all

Comment: Who is Plot? What's the actual message in the log? Is there more information than a single corruption? What advice are you looking for? There isn't really question as your own testing showed that apparently the Storage Space isn't (directly) responsible?

Comment: With your progression so far you already know it is possible, does have problems and it issues. You'd have to let it run and do transactions for a while in order to see whenever there will be more issues along the road. Having more people try that would certainly be helpful. Thanks for updating the question! I'm not really familiar with how Storage Spaces work so maybe there's an issue in regards how data is written and read?

Comment: @Seth the little remark in InnoDB config docs, about NTFS is peculiar. They (ORACLE, I assume) basically suggest not to use NTFS at all? I think we are here best to avoid and not enter into very stormy seas indeed :)  I create on simple NTFS drive then move the data folder to  Storage Spaces and all is fine. So far.